# Binary tree in-order python

Tags: stack, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search, expression-trees

I'm creating a binary tree and I'm stuck to convert it to postfix and infix. The problem is that I'm trying to create a method `infix` and `postfix` inside the class but it doesn’t  work:

> TypeError: Node.Postfix() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = key

    def Postfix(self):
            if Node:
              self.Postfix(self.left)
              self.Postfix(self.right)
              print(Node.val, end=" ")

X="- + a b * * e f g"

r=Node.constructTree(X)

r.Postfix()
```

I'm building my tree using the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you use `Postfix` method with an argument, but it doesn't accept one.

In Python the methods are like functions, but their first argument (`self`) is an object. So, to call the `Postfix` method on the left subtree use should use `self.left.Postfix()`.

Another problem is that before calling `Postfix` you should test if the subtree exists. And you should use `self.val` instead of `Node.val` to get a value of the node.

If you fix all these errors you get something like this:

```py
def Postfix(self):
    if self.left:
        self.left.Postfix()
    if self.right:
        self.right.Postfix()
    print(self.val, end=" ")
```